# Where is noscript source code in Tor browser bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, source-code, noscript

I'm trying to find the source code of noscript in the Tor browser bundle, usually (given how firefox does it) it should be under `<uniqueID>.default/extensions`, however with Tor browser bundle all I'm seeing is a few items:

```
total 7768
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff   1.7M Feb 13 08:13 https-everywhere-eff@eff.org.xpi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff   708K Feb 13 08:13 tor-launcher@torproject.org.xpi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff   818K Feb 13 08:13 torbutton@torproject.org.xpi
-rw-r--r--@ 1 admin  staff   612K Feb 13 08:13 {73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232}.xpi
```

I've extracted and looked at each one of these against noscripts `xpi` but can't seem to understand (or am overlooking) where the browser bundle delivers noscript. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i'm pretty sure `73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232.xpi` is the noscript addon.

Answer (score 1):

[`73a6fe31-595d-460b-a920-fcc0f8843232.xpi` is the NoScript addon](https://www.systemlookup.com/FF_Extensions/21-73a6fe31_595d_460b_a920_fcc0f8843232_xpi.html)